# Visual Basic adding number loop

Tags: vb.net, winforms, basic

I am trying to make an idle game something like cookie clicker, and I am having problems with making a simple line of code that repeats every second and adds 5 to a number every second. Could anyone help me? I want this to start the loop if someone clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a timer.  Enable/start the timer when the button is clicked.

See example at MSDN: [Windows Form Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

add a timer and in the button code type :

```
TimerName.start
```

and add this in the timer code :

```
TimerName.interval = 1000
'replace TimerName with the name of timer you just added
'this will add 5 to number you want every second , interval of timer = 1000 that means it does the code every second
NumberThatYouWant += 5
'Replace NameThatYouWant with the number name that you want to add 5 to it every second
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah create a timer, then set the timer.interval to 1000 to tick each second, then create a sub for timer.tick and put the number you want to be increased in there and that should work.

EG.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick() Handles Timer1.Tick
    variable += 5
End Sub
```

You have to change the interval in the properties window (bottom right)

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** I didn't include Timer1.start because the other answers said that. Don't forget to use it.

Answer (score 0):

## Setting the Timer

First, add a **timer** control to your form. Set the timer's interval value to '1000' (the timer's interval is measured in milliseconds). You should also enable your timer at run-time:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

So your code should look similar to this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
End Sub
```

## Adding the value with the Timer

Now say the button's name is 'button1', we will now finish the code to add 5 to the button's text property every 1 second, like so:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Button1.Text += 5
End Sub
```

This code can also be written as "Button1.Text = Button1.Text + 5" I hope this helps clear up the ambiguity.